# How to change Angular Material expansion panel arrow icon to plus(+) and minus(-)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the  as per requirement. The expansion arrow has to change. I have checked for the align option, but I didn't get what I need.

Comment: Do you have any written code? any error log? please consider to check [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could define global styles (e.g. in `styles.css`) that would override Angular's styles:

```css
mat-expansion-panel-header .mat-expansion-indicator::after {
  content: "+";
  border: 0;
  transform: none;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded .mat-expansion-indicator::after {
  content: "-";
}
```

[image]